# How to embed image in Azure Logic App Send Email Office 365 Connector?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Currently, I have Stored Image in Blob and referred  the same in email body using HTML image tag.
But when email is recived to thr user, Blob url is getting exposed in pane as PFB:

[image]

> I don't want to expose the blob url for image.

Comment: just add the image as an attachment, use the get blob content action. Is it for logic app ? do you need some sample ?

Comment: @Thomas I need to display Image in email body as a brand, currently i i have used blob url in Email body.

Comment: convert the content to base64, check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Comment: @Thomas yeah but, when i use base64 then Logic app template gives error of Maximum template limit exceeded. so needed workaround